# Unable to create a linked service in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, service, cloud, storage, factory

I am trying to create a linked service in Azure Data Factory using Authentication method as Account Key ,however getting error as :

> Fail to connect to
>   https://stlptsecurestoragetst.blob.core.windows.net/: Error Message:
>   The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. (ErrorCode: 403,
>   Detail: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.,
>   RequestId: 07c79a90-001e-0016-2142-d62fc9000000), make sure the
>   credential provided is valid. The remote server returned an error:
>   (403) Forbidden.StorageExtendedMessage=, The remote server returned an
>   error: (403) Forbidden. Activity ID:
>   d0e05dbb-d3a9-46fc-bd2d-69592c4b5183.

Comment: can you provide more information to clarify what you've tried?

Comment: Hi geshu, If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. If it doesn't work, please let me know, we are glad to help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the role to assign access to your Data Factory like this:

Storage accout-->Access Contol(IAM)--> Add a role assignment:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: It didn't help in my case. I also have specified the data factory name in the resource instances in the networking screen for the blob storage.