# DataFlow activity of Datafactory is not supporting Azure Storage with keyvault getting error "account is a required property for AzureBlobStorage"

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

We have azure datafactory where we are using DataFlow activity and for getting data from blob we are using AzureblobStorage. Even in AzurefileSystem dataset it is getting succeeded.

[image]

[image]

We can see it is working correctly with required keyvault settings. *Connection Successful* in box. But when we tried to connect in DataFactory, it was getting error "Account is required property for AzureBlobStorage"

[image]

We tried this connection with Copy Data activity but it worked. Seems DataFlow is not supporting Storage Connection with keyVault.

Please let me know if any solution or alternatives you guys have.

Comment: Is this any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706462/azure-data-factory-connecting-to-blob-storage-via-access-key

Comment: Not exactly.. I am trying to access KeyVault based storage linked service and trying to access in existing data flow activity. It works perfectly in Copy activity but seems it does not support in DataFlow.